# What is the best way to create that kind of gradient glowing?

Tags: emission

Hi. I've been trying to create this kind of glowing object for quite a while now, but I can't figure it out. I've tried mixing different colors of emitting, my problem is I can't get them to blend nicely and give it a circle shape.
Is there a way I can do it using weight paint? What would be the best way to create that kind of glowing object?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Gradient Texture (Spherical type) controlling the Factor input of a Mix Shader may be what you're going for:

[image]

Comment: Instead of using the Color Ramp as a factor for two shaders, I'd just put the blue colors in the ramp instead of the black and black ticks, and plug that in a single Emission node's color input. That would be simpler to manage, and two fewer nodes to compute for Blender.

Comment: Originally I didn't use a Color Ramp to control the Gradient (I was trying to keep it simple), but added it to make the effect more obvious.  And we don't know how this'll be implemented -- it may be two Emission shaders, or it may be an Emission vs a Principled BDSF.